# Java - Why can't I play any sounds?

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to load sounds into a game and it's just not working after watching half a dozen different YouTube tutorials.

This is the last thing I tried:

```
    public static Mixer mixer;
public static Mixer.Info[] info;
public static DataLine.Info dataline;
public static AudioInputStream stream;

public static Clip title;
public static Clip click;

public static void init()
{
    info = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info[0]);
    dataline = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);

    title = load("/music/title");

    click = load("/effects/click");
}

public static void play(Clip clip)
{
    clip.start();
}

public static void stop(Clip clip)
{
    clip.stop();
}

public static Clip load(String path)
{
    Clip clip = null;

    try
    {
        clip = (Clip) mixer.getLine(dataline);
        URL file = Sounds.class.getResource("/assets/sounds/effects/" + path + ".wav");
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        clip.open(stream);
    }
    catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clip;
}
```

And when loading a sound I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:207)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:841)
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:178)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1147)
at data.resources.Sounds.load(Sounds.java:54)
at data.resources.Sounds.init(Sounds.java:31)
at data.Game.init(Game.java:60)
at data.Game.run(Game.java:69)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The files are located in:
    res/assets/sounds/effects/clip.wav
    res/assets/sounds/music/title.wav

I've tried:
    /res/assets/...
    res/assets/...
    /assets/...
    assets/...

I've tried:
    .wav
    .mp3
    .ogg
    .wma
    .m4a

And no combination of them works. The files are NOT corrupt. They play perfectly fine in VLC, Windows Media Player and also when replacing Minecraft's music files (as .ogg's) with them. So they are recognised and playable in both Java and in normal players.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is simply no resource at the path you are specifying. Are you sure that 1) the files are on the classpath; 2) you're passing in the correct path, e.g. are you supplying the ".wav" in the parameter `path`?

Comment: Incidentally, you can(/should) remove all but 1 (or maybe 2) lines of this code from the question: you only need the one where you call `getResource`, and maybe the one where you call `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream`. Everything else looks irrelevant, since this is simply a matter of not specifying the correct resource path.